# Issue With Casting MdiChildren

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, forms, casting

I am having a casting issue with `MdiChildren`.

This works:

```
MyForm mf = (MyForm)this.ActiveMdiChild;
```

this does not work:

```
MyForm[] mfs = (MyForm[])this.MdiChildren;
```

All forms in the parent form are instances of `MyForm`, But I cannot successfully cast them.  This means that I cannot use any of the methods that `MyForm` provides because they are only Form objects.  What can I do to rectify this issue?

Comment: Why do you need a separate collection (array) from MdiChildren? Why not iterate over that collection and cast individually as needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MdiChildren](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdichildren.aspx) property returns an array of `Form` instances, which is not the same thing as (and is not directly convertible to) an array of `MyForm` instances.

You can use LINQ's [Cast()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) method to perform an explicit conversion:

```
MyForm[] mfs = this.MdiChildren.Cast<MyForm>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it;

```
IEnumerable<MyForm> mfs = this.MdiChildren.Cast<MyForm>();
```